# Can i install the GRUB boot loader manually on kali linux virual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, debian, grub, kali-linux, bootloader

while i was installing kali linux on my virtual machine i selected No for "Install the GRUB boot loader to the master boot record?" and the system decided not to boot, is there another way to install the GRUB boot loader and relocate it manually so the system boot again instead of deleting the virtual machine and reinstall it again ?

Comment: If you think you don't need a bootloader and you need to ask this question here, **you shouldn't be using Kali, period**.

Comment: You must install Grub as part of the machine install process. Been there, done that, and it is necessary

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Kali inside a VM (VMware and Hyper-V both).

Installing the Grub boot loader is an integral part of setting up the machine and I did that for both machines.

Without the Grub loader, the Kali machine will not start.

I do not think (after some testing) that you can install the Grub loader manually in the virtual machine. I did not see a way to do that.

Best advice: Make a new Kali VM, and be sure to install the Grub loader.  Since your machine did not start (as expected), reinstalling a new VM is not a big deal at this point.

Posted from my Kali 2023.2 VM.

**Follow up:**

Kali is now at 2023.3 and you further may wish to download the newest version and make a new VM.

Comment: Sure you can by booting a live session, `chroot`ìng and finally installing Grub where it should be. That said, between the aforementioned process and redoing it there may not be such a difference in wasted time so...

Comment: The author is using a VM and since Grub was not installed as it should have been, it is easy just to redo the installation.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I said. I was also correcting this wrong assertion: *do not think (after some testing) that you can install the Grub loader manually. I did not see a way to do that.*